# Davening a long shemoneh esrei and missing ameins

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, time, tzibur-community, amen

Is there anything wrong/are there any problems with a person davening a long shemoneh esrei, so much so that they miss chazaras hashatz, including kedusha, and all the ameins...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh - Yalqut Yosef, Siman 109:6](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0028_L2) states:

> ומי שמאריך בתפלתו באופן שהצבור מסיימים להתפלל ערבית, והוא עדיין בתפלתו, ובליל ח' לחודש שהצבור מברך ברכת הלבנה, מפסיד אמירת הברכה ברוב עם, יש לו להשתדל להתרגל לכוין מהר, כדי שיסיים את התפלה ויאמר ברכת הלבנה עם הצבור ברוב עם. אבל אם הצבור מתפלל יותר מדאי במהירות, והוא מתעכב לצורך כוונה הכרחית בביאור המלים, אין בכך כלום שמפסיד אמירת ברכת הלבנה ברוב עם, אחר דתפלה בלא כוונה כגוף בלא נשמה. ומכל מקום ישתדל להתרגל לכוין מהר גם כדי להרויח עניית קדיש

The last sentence is crucial here in that "one should accustom oneself to concentrate while praying a bit more quickly [...] to merit responding to Qaddish".

Nevertheless, if a tzibbur prays far too quickly for one to concentrate, one should only pray as quickly as possible without sacrificing concentration.

Comment: He does seem to limit it to when they say *kidush levana* after maariv, no? Is *chararas hashatz* more important? (e.g. What would be for *mincha* instead of *maariv*)?

Comment: In the last sentence, he seems to state that, in general, one should accustom oneself to speed a tiny bit so as to merit answering Amen to Qaddish.

Comment: A crucial omission from your English summary: The *Kitzur* writes that a slow congregant should make efforts to become accustomed to being able to concentrate at a faster pace. By implication, until he is actually successful in doing so, the need for at least a minimal level of concentration (i.e. attention to the plain meaning of the words) takes precedence over answering *amein* to *d'varim she'bikdusha*. See also *Sha'arei T'shuva* (OC 52:1) who writes that the need to concentrate takes precedence, though one should try to time his prayers so that he can answer to *bar'chu* and *k'dusha*.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your comments, though I think they are accurately reflected in or implied by my English summary.

Comment: @Lee Well, even if the congregation is praying at a reasonable pace, one should still in fact lengthen his prayers if that is necessary for him to concentrate. He should just try to train himself to eventually concentrate faster, though. I thought that your summary might be read to imply otherwise, hence my comment.

Comment: @Fred I added a translation of the last sentence of the pesaq which I think clarifies the matter.

Answer (score 0):

In Minhagei Lita (a sefer about Litvishe minhagim), he says that it is not right to daven long at the expense of missing Kedusha.

However, halachically speaking, as long as you start on time (together with everyone else), you may in fact daven as long as you want, and listen to Kedusha (shomea k'oneh).